# Vercel - Deployment without promotion

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, vercel

Is there a way to create a deployment of my Nextjs app to production but without promoting it immediately to prod? Similar to a preview URL, but without public traffic being routed to that URL.

My use case is that I want to deploy a "pre-prod" app, run E2E tests there, and if they are successful, promote the app to production.

Is this flow possible?

I've used `vercel --prod`, but that just deploys the current version to production.
I want to create a production build that allows me to then use the `alias` command to point the traffic to a specific version.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://vercel.com/support/articles/set-up-a-staging-environment-on-vercel

Comment: thanks! I saw that, but staging will have different env variables than prod, and if I wanted to "promote" it, it would need a complete rebuild. What I'm after is a deployment that would have the same variables as prod, but without routing traffic to it so that I can later promote it immediately after testing

Answer (score 0):

In this case, my opinion, you need to create an "intermediate" solution.

In vercel, you have "dev" "preview" and "production" environments (go to Settings-environment variables). You set some settings to `preview` env, it's ok for you, you can after "promote to `production`" your `preview` version.

Also, you can set up a special branch in git to directly deployment on `preview`